# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, exercise with modules and objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, object, module

I'm a rookie coder.
I just learned syntax, some basics concepts about modules and objects.
Now I'm trying to put everything together in small computer game.

I created two files. On the end of the "actions.py" file I tried to check changes in value of "victim's" healthPoints. During the print tests (file called "actions.py") I get error after second print statement :

```
Python actions.py 
1) valume of chicken's health: 44 Traceback 
(most recent call last):   File "actions.py", line 17, in <module> fight(dog, chicken)   File "actions.py", line 5, 
in fight damage = attacker.hit() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

tools.py:

```
from random import randint
""" Objects in the game """

# Characters
class Character(object):
    """General Class for characters in the game"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.strengh = 0
        self.healthPoints = 0
        damageAtrr = 0

    def hit(self):
        self.hit = self.strengh/2 + randint(1,10) + self.healthPoints / 100
        return self.hit

    def setDamage(self, damage):
        Character.damageAtrr = damage

    def getDamage(self):
        """
        function which take value from
        setDamage and calculate new value for
        healthPoints
        """
        self.healthPoints = self.healthPoints - Character.damageAtrr
        return self.healthPoints


class hero(Character):
    """
    Main character in the game
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.strengh = 8
        self.healthPoints = 50

class villan(Character):
    """
    Villans in the game
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.strengh = 5
        self.healthPoints = 50
```

second file with function that causes problems, "actions.py":

```
import tools

# action that causes damage to the victim
def fight(attacker, victim):
    damage = attacker.hit()
    victim.setDamage(damage)
    victim.healthPoints = victim.getDamage()

chicken = tools.hero("Terry")
dog = tools.villan("Max")

#attacker is dog, victim is chicken

fight(dog, chicken)
print "1) valume of chicken's health: %d" % chicken.healthPoints

fight(dog, chicken)
print "2)chicken's health:: %d" % chicken.healthPoints

fight(dog, chicken)
print "3)chicken's health:: %d" % chicken.healthPoints

fight(dog, chicken)
print "4)chicken's health:: %d" % chicken.healthPoints

fight(dog, chicken)
print "5)chicken's health:: %d" % chicken.healthPoints

fight(dog, chicken)
print "6)chicken's health:: %d" % chicken.healthPoints
```

I don't know what exactly causes the problem: I expected that everytime when I call function 'fight', health of the chicken will decrease.

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hit field is just a attribute but not a method of Obj. So, you should access it by using: `damage = attacker.hit`

Answer (score 0):

In `tools.py`, you define the `Character` class.  In that class, you define a method `hit()`.  That method you later call in `actions.py` in the `fight()` function.  In `hit()`, you say `self.hit = ...`  When you do that, you are overwriting `self.hit()`.  In Python, methods are still attributes.  When you define an attribute with the same name as a method, you overwrite the method.  In this case, you don't even use `self.hit` other than as a method.  In `hit()`, just take out the `self.` before the two occurrences of `self.hit`